# Permission denied error when using easy_install

Tags: 14.04, permissions, system-installation, python

I am trying to use easy_install to install seaborn, a python package. I found however that easy_install is giving me issues for anything I try to install. I recive the following error message:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/test-easy-install-18534.write-test'
```

There is also an explanation that suggests I do not have administration permissions. This is not the case. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you `easy_install` or `sudo easy_install`?

Comment: I did `easy_install`. Now am using `sudo easy_install` and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use sudo. Even if your logged in user has admin privileges, you need to use sudo for the command to have them. (Unless you are logged in as root, but you don't want ot do that)